# Continue executing javascript code after window.location is set to call a get method in controller?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I set the window.location to a call a get method in my ASP.NET Controller which returns a FileResult and then starts the download on client side.

How could I continue some code after the file was returned to the page. I can't execute JavaScript code after window.location is set.

The user enters some data in a form and expect the page to return a file as response. The page may **not** be reloaded. At first I tried calling the controller method (ASP.NET GET) with an Ajax method but I found out that I can't return a file as Ajax result.

So I set the window.location to the action and the download starts just like it should.

The problem that I am not able to solve is that I need to refresh the view by using some of my async Ajax methods after the download.

```
    function offlineAktivieren(element) {
        // prepare some data
        var id = "xxx";
        var code = "xxx";

        // redirect to post action
        window.location = '/controller/getmethod?id=' + id + '&code=' + code;

        // MY GOAL
        // execute code after window.location
        // refreshContent(element);
    }
```

I expect code to be executed after the call of window.location. How could i archieve this?

**Update:**
With window.open() I can execute javascript but then i need to wait for eindow.open() to finish somehow.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a `Windows.location` you can call ajax request or just

```
window.open('/controller/getmethod?id=' + id + '&code=' + code);
```

So your code will be something like that

```
function offlineAktivieren(element) {
    // prepare some data
    var id = "xxx";
    var code = "xxx";

    // redirect to post action
    window.open('/controller/getmethod?id=' + id + '&code=' + code);

    // MY GOAL
    // execute code after window.location
    // refreshContent(element);
}
```

Comment: window.open allows me to execute code after the call but it will not wait for the execution of window.open which drives me into the next problem.

Is there a way to wait until window.open() finishes without a hardcoded timeout?

Comment: I think you should go with ajax because you have the finish event and we that you can control that finish of download

Answer (score 0):

Your `windows.location` basically change the url but dont executes or loads.
try one of the following to make the happen.

```
window.location.assign(url);
window.location.href = url;
```

Comment: Why should he do that? What does that do? How should he use them? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer